# Calculation of residual loss for VDSR in Keras

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I am using Keras with backend tensorflow. I download the code for very deep super resolution cnn from (https://github.com/GeorgeSeif/VDSR-Keras) and try to train my own model. The model is compile with mean square error (mse) but the original model have residual loss. How to implement residual loss in keras. Residual loss can be calculate as

```
loss = (label - input_image - predected_image)^2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom loss function and assign that.
I'm not sure how residual loss works, but if youre able to calculate it you can implement it like so.

```
def residual_loss(): #<- this is just rought example, youre going to have to figure this out.
  ....
  return loss

model.compile(adam, loss=residual_loss, metrics=[PSNR, "accuracy"])
```

Comment: Thanks you so much.. but  how and from where the method will get the input arguments..label_image, input_image and predected_image. because the custom function have take two arguments i.e. y_true, and y_pred.

Answer (score 0):

The VDSR model is following:

```
input_img = Input(shape=IMG_SIZE)

model = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), padding='same', kernel_initializer='he_normal')(input_img)
model = Activation('relu')(model)
model = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), padding='same', kernel_initializer='he_normal')(model)
model = Activation('relu')(model)
model = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), padding='same', kernel_initializer='he_normal')(model)
model = Activation('relu')(model)
model = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), padding='same', kernel_initializer='he_normal')(model)
model = Activation('relu')(model)
model = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), padding='same', kernel_initializer='he_normal')(model)
model = Activation('relu')(model)

model = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), padding='same', kernel_initializer='he_normal')(model)
model = Activation('relu')(model)
model = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), padding='same', kernel_initializer='he_normal')(model)
model = Activation('relu')(model)
model = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), padding='same', kernel_initializer='he_normal')(model)
model = Activation('relu')(model)
model = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), padding='same', kernel_initializer='he_normal')(model)
model = Activation('relu')(model)
model = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), padding='same', kernel_initializer='he_normal')(model)
model = Activation('relu')(model)

model = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), padding='same', kernel_initializer='he_normal')(model)
model = Activation('relu')(model)
model = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), padding='same', kernel_initializer='he_normal')(model)
model = Activation('relu')(model)
model = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), padding='same', kernel_initializer='he_normal')(model)
model = Activation('relu')(model)
model = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), padding='same', kernel_initializer='he_normal')(model)
model = Activation('relu')(model)
model = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), padding='same', kernel_initializer='he_normal')(model)
model = Activation('relu')(model)

model = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), padding='same', kernel_initializer='he_normal')(model)
model = Activation('relu')(model)
model = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), padding='same', kernel_initializer='he_normal')(model)
model = Activation('relu')(model)
model = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), padding='same', kernel_initializer='he_normal')(model)
model = Activation('relu')(model)
model = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), padding='same', kernel_initializer='he_normal')(model)
model = Activation('relu')(model)
model = Conv2D(1, (3, 3), padding='same', kernel_initializer='he_normal')(model)
res_img = model

output_img = add([res_img, input_img])

model = Model(input_img, output_img)
```

The input image for the model is a block of image patches (a patch has resolution 41 x 41 pixels with 8 bits/pixel).
In your formula:
loss = (label - input_image - predected_image)^2 =(label - (input_image + predected_image))^2) where input_image + predected_image it is the newtork output. The network learn correction (line output_img = add([res_img, input_img])) of scaled input image to overcome the effect of bicubic interpolation which is not the best approach for the image super-resolution.